How to design and Implement dynamic components in .NET Form apps?

In here I need get all products from the API and how to loop products..this products component is groupbox in .NET forms. when user click add btn need to add that product to right side groupBox panel.
How to loop this custom .NET components ? or Is there have any prefered components in toolbox?
please suggest the best and easy solution to dynamically render the products ?
